# View collective data from all tables using a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

I have 20 tables and want to see the data of all tables with one query. Is there any way I could do this?

The tables, `join/converge` on 2 columns. Also, is it possible to view the collective data directly on `XAMPP`?

Answer (score 0):

It's completely based on how your tables connected to each other and you need a little knowledge to utilize your mysql server to do that for you.

In practice let's say you have a table for customers and a table for products and a relation between them indicating which customer bought which product (which also a table in this case):

`Customers (id, username, password, fullname, email)`

`Products (id, name, sku, price)`

`Customers_Products (customer_id, product_id, created_at)`

And we want to get a list of all products sold from May:

`SELECT c.fullname, p.name, p.sku, p.created_at FROM Products AS p INNER JOIN Customers_Products AS cp ON p.id=cp.product_id INNER JOIN Customers as c ON c.id=cp.customer_id WHERE created_at > '2015-05-01 00:00:00';`

I wrote this example to show you that doing this is completely depends on your requirements which can be very simple like selecting data from just one table to very complicated like joining multiple tables while filtering, grouping and ordering them.

For your next question. Yes It's possible you can see what's on your tables from phpMyAdmin but usually this is not a good solution since a user in phpMyAdmin can see the plumbing part of your system. The other way that most people use is to write some code to acquire the data and show them to the user.

Comment: How could I as a developer see the collective data in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: You can write raw queries and run them, also you can create views in mysql which are accessible by phpMyAdmin